# Angularjs Use injectect module's controller in route definition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-module

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to modularlize my app.

My main module gets some other module and I want to use the controller of the injected module in my route definition.
Some simple example would be very helpful!

This does not work:

```
var app = angular.module('Contacting_App', ['LeadLookup']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.
                        when('/main', 
                            {controller: 'MainCtrl', 
                            templateUrl: 'apex/f42_Contacting_Main'}
                        ).
                        when('/lead', 
                            {module: 'LeadLookup',
                            controller: 'LeadLkpCtrl', 
                            templateUrl: 'apex/f42_Lead_Lookup'}
                        ).
                        otherwise(
                            {redirectTo: '/main'}
                        );
                }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial page may point you in the correct direction docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

The main things you should look at are:

Module

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatControllers'
]);
```

routeProvider

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

Controllers

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module('phonecatControllers', []);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);

phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
  function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
  }]);
```

Comment: thanks for responding!
maybe i should explain what i want to do more in detail:
on the /main page is a button which leads to the /lead page. some data gets fetched here by the LeadLkpCtrl and will get passed by a service (which is not present here yet) back to the MainCtrl.
At least this is what I'm planning to do .. if theres a better way I would be happy to hear about ;)

Comment: so basically this part does not work:
when('/lead', 
                            {module: 'LeadLookup',
                            controller: 'LeadLkpCtrl', 
                            templateUrl: 'apex/f42_Lead_Lookup'}
                        )

Comment: sharing the data is not my problem here ;) I want to tell angular to use the LeadLkpCtrl for /lead route - thats it :)

Comment: no i found it in a post ... I was confused as well when i was not able to find this attribute in the docs ...

Comment: @MarcoSchmit This tutorial page may point you in the correct direction https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07. The info in "The App Module" and "Controllers" seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: ok theres no need for some "module" attribute or whatever ... just injecting the module and its usable in the route definition. I just got some copy paste failure which caused previous trials not to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarcoSchmit Glad to be of help. I'll edit my answer to incorporate my comment for anyone that comes across this question.